# SAPUI5 Application is not setting external API data to JSON model

Tags: xml, api, rest, sapui5

I'm trying to render a stock price retrieved from an API endpoint into a tile control of a SAPUI5 application. I have the following setup in the controller file:

```
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel, 'stockinfo');

        // load data from URL
        oModel.loadData('https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/dax/quote?displayPercent=true');
        oModel.attachRequestCompleted(function() {
            var data = oModel.getData();
            console.log('data', data);
            this.getView().getModel('stockinfo').setData(data);
        });
```

When I try to bind this to a control, nothing renders:

```
            <GenericTile
                class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin sapUiTinyMarginTop"
                header="{i18n>startpageUserReviewsTileTitle}"
                press="onNavToReviews">
                <tileContent>
                    <TileContent>
                        <content>
                            <NumericContent 
                                value = "{
                                path:'stockinfo>/latestPrice'
                                }" 
                                scale = "%"
                            />
                        </content>
                    </TileContent>
                </tileContent>
            </GenericTile>
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with my setup?

Comment: can you add the structure of you json model? there might be the issue

Comment: thanks, the json structure wasn't the problem, see the answer I have included below :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. From the SAP docs

> Load JSON-encoded data from the server using a GET HTTP request and store the resulting JSON data in the model. Note: Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy, the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

I basically just removed the extraneous 'attachRequestCompleted' and the setModel method: sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel, 'stockinfo')

All the code that is needed:

```
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        oModel.loadData('https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/dax/quote?displayPercent=true');
        this.setModel(oModel, 'stockinfo');
```